# Page doesn't load after press F5

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am working in ASP.NET 3.5 C# and SQL Server 2005. Also I am using LINQ to SQL.

The project was working fine since 1 year.

Suddenly I got this output from yesterday and it doesn't load login page also. It stops loading after the last line of output

> 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'

**Is it LINQ error? Or anything related to WebDev.WebServer.exe?**

I checked in GAC, I have webdev.webserver dll, manifest and exe.

**Error:**

> 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.EXE', Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\WebDev.WebHost\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\WebDev.WebHost.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CppCodeProvider\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\CppCodeProvider.dll'
>   'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\appointment\f1bc9095\26b546e2\assembly\dl3\1658e797\00f5b014_095dc901\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL',
>   Symbols loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\appointment\f1bc9095\26b546e2\assembly\dl3\b5f58b02\00f07c5b_10f3c801\MCN.WebControls.DLL'
>   'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\appointment\f1bc9095\26b546e2\App_Code.frd1cmfw.dll', Symbols
>   loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\appointment\f1bc9095\26b546e2\App_global.asax.a8zsvehh.dll',
>   Symbols loaded. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded
>   'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'

Answer (score 0):

sneha, are you trying to debug your application by attaching w3wp.exe..and i guess you are trying to debug using IE...

Try Building before debug, it can be disabled in project properties...

Comment: No, I am trying to debug in Firefiox. When you say attaching w3wp.exe, does it mean I should not attach it? I cannot see this exe file in C:\Windows\System32

Comment: Hi Mayank, I don't understand the relation between the output lines and issue i fixed, but by doing so it solved my issue. In global.asax I called 2 methods in app_start(), it was running fine from 1 year. suddenly it stopped working due to this. i commented the line where i call the function and now its working. Thanks for taking effort in helping me.

Comment: nice to know you solved it...hope it'll be helpful for others too.. :)

Comment: yes but do you use skype? as i stay online on skype 24*7 otherwise i will add you in gmail